# How to getDistance from userLocation every 4-5 seconds

Tags: iphone, mapkit, userlocation

I'm not using this for driving directions or similar. I have a few annotations and want a trigger when user is in the vicinity of one of those, so I can alert the user.

It seems didUpdateToLocation is called only once per startUpdatingLocation call? At least when I NSLog within that method, I only get one line in console. No, I'm not walking around with the iphone.

So: What is the correct way to set up a continuous monitoring of userLocation and get a "callback" (either when 3-4 seconds have passed or when user has moved say, 10 meters)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you probably know, this is the code to initialize and start the location manager:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

And implement *didUpdateToLocation* like this:

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation*)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation*) oldLocation 
{
   // This will be called every time the device has any new location information. 
}
```

The system will call `didUpdateToLocation` every time there is an update to the location. If the system does not detect a change in location `didUpdateToLocation` will not be called. The only thing you can do is to set the `distanceFilter` and `desiredAccuracy` like i did in the example to give you the highest accuracy.

**Update**

Use kCLLocationAccuracyBest instead of kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters for more accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I couldn't think of a way right away to patch userLocation to be able to test that properly. 

I'll just implement the distance-alerter there and let someone test it live. It's actually better than using a time interval.

Is accuracy=best and filter=10m the same thing, and if not, why not? (If you know.)

Comment: You are right, kCLLocationAccuracyBest is better. Pretty sure that kCLDistanceFilterNone is the best. Documentation says its all notifications when using kCLDistanceFilterNone.

Comment: Well, actually I meant that moving 10 meters is a good criterion for frequent enough updates without getting them too often (or while standing still, which you'd get if you set both to 'best/none'?)

So I just wondered which of "accuracy=best+filter=10m" and "accuracy=10m+filter=none" gave the most proper results, sort of, that was all. :)

Comment: Ah. I have not tested the different values in real life, so can't help you with that.